# What monetary system did Hobbits use in the Shire?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, money, hobbits

In Book I, Chapter 3 of *The Lord of the Rings*, Tolkien wrote, "Just why Mr. Frodo was selling his beautiful hole was even more debatable than the price."

After appreciating this example of (probably) unconscious humor, it led me to wonder: Hobbits and other races of Middle-earth did use coins as money; they are mentioned in [several places](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Money). In the LOTR appendices, Tolkien gave us a tremendous amount of information about the languages, scripts, calendars, and chronology of Middle-earth, but didn't write a comparable treatment of money, which is odd considering that European histories often do include a page or two about the value of such coins as florins and ducats. Perhaps he described the Hobbit monetary system in detail elsewhere in his voluminous published and unpublished writings. What, in sum, do we know about the Hobbit monetary system?

Comment: Is it clear that hobbits had their own "monetary system", they didn't just use Gondorian coins? Remind me, it's been over half a century since I read *The Lord of the Rings*.

Comment: They certainly *could* use coins of Gondor, although it's rather a long way off, and there's little long-distance traffic by the late Third Age.  If hobbits did not mint their own coinage, they probably used a hodge podge of whatever drifted in from other lands.  Quite possibly there are still a fair number of coins floating around from when the Shire was part of Arnor/Arthedain.

Comment: Realistically, if the population was stable, and there wasn't a whole economy where everybody worked and was paid in money, as long as people don't lose too many coins, the same money could just go around and around for centuries without minting more — especially with the odd cash injection like Bilbo's.

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine That would be true in a society whose population was stable, but it's pretty clear that the peaceful Shire underwent a population explosion in the centuries since its founding. I'm not saying that the Shire minted its own coins, but if they did not, then the coins' value would have steadily increased as there were fewer available per person.

Comment: It would be logical to conjecture that Dwarves minted coins from the metals that they mined, and used them to pay for food grown by neighboring Men and maybe Hobbits. But, as Mustapha Mond pointed out, there were some aspects of culture that did not interest J. R. R. Tolkien.

Comment: @Invisible Trihedron: For instance, the Hobbits, dwarves, and random travellers like Strider & Gandalf, all were obviously able to pay their bills at the Prancing Pony in Bree without difficulty.

Comment: Why, they used HobBitCoin, naturally.

Comment: Since the Shire is based on pre-war rural England, they clearly used pounds, shillings, and pence.

Comment: It is possible they didn't use coins for transactions like this at all. In a stable society where everyone broadly speaking trusts everyone else, money can exist as accounts or other tokens without cash. This is true of ancient as well as modern societies. In Mediaeval England tally sticks were used quite a bit (for instance) as Tolkien should have known.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not aware of any description of the monetary system, but since Tolkien was a medieval scholar and the Shire seems to be a representation of England, I assume his internal thought was medieval English denominations. It certainly is not a modern system, since the sale of Bill Ferny's pony is six *silver* pennies, and pennies are usually copper post-medieval. I had thought that the medieval values were derived from the Roman system, which had 60 gold solidus per pound of gold, however, things seem to have become a mess [1].

There is a summary of Richard II's coinage [2] that seems like a reasonable mental model for Hobbit currency.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A3sd

[2] https://archives.history.ac.uk/richardII/coinage.html

Comment: In Britain, pennies were minted in silver for general circulation until the late 17th century, and continued to be minted until the late 18th century. Britain didn't start minting copper pennies until the very late 18th century (though private copper tokens were circulating before then). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(British_pre-decimal_coin)

Comment: While each of the answers have been thoughtful, this one seems to be the most useful for understanding how Tolkien thought *and wrote* about money in the Shire. Silver pennies: That's a good point indeed.

Answer (score 43):

Basically, nothing.  There are a handful of references to specific coins, primarily in the Bree section of FOTR.  Bill Ferny sells a pony for 12 silver pennies; Barliman Butterbur makes an allusion to a gold piece being of substantial value.  Other than that, there are scattered references to money but nothing specific.  We might surmise that the chests of gold and silver that Bilbo brought back from the Lonely Mountain are primarily coinage.

There was a brief mention of "double dragons" as a type of gold coin in the Shire in an early draft of "A Long Expected Party" but it got dropped in subsequent drafts.  In general, it seems clear that nothing was ever detailed by Tolkien, and that monetary systems did not interest him.

Comment: History of Middle-Earth does contain a very brief mention of Gondor coinage - the castar, comprised of four tharni.  This is in a section on translation, and is not expanded on further, and did not make it into the published LOTR.

Answer (score 26):

Until European rulers discovered fiat currency by adulterating the coinage, coins simply had the value of however much they weighed.  There was no need for exchange rates, because you just weighed the coins and that was what they were worth.  Standard-sized coins gave convenient ranges of values which reduced the need for weighing, but ultimately the weight was the value.

This meant that although every country around Europe had its own sizes of coins, there was no real "monetary system" as we would understand it today with fiat currency and exchange rates.  The "monetary system" was simply that a certain weight of gold or silver was worth a certain weight of gold or silver, and that was all there was to it.

In the absence of a major centralising authority in Middle Earth, it seems likely that this would be the same there too.  This is purely hypothetical though, and Tolkien hasn't given us strong evidence of any of this, beyond the fact (per Smaug's hoard in *The Hobbit*) that coins do exist.

Comment: While very correct in terms of the statements made, this doesn't answer the question at all.  While a shilling was literally worth its weight in silver (likely a troy ounce, given there were twelve to the pound sterling), pence, shillings, pounds and so forth carries a much different flavor from dollars and cents or *sou* and *franc*.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Added to the final paragraph to make it a bit clearer about answering the question.

Comment: Adulteration of coinage goes back into ancient times. (It's a pretty obvious idea if you are minting coins and short of bullion...)

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is even true within its own frame of reference: if you have coins *at all*, you have some system for labelling and exchanging them. Just because you could theoretically melt down a certain number of *denarii* and re-cast them as a certain number of *drachmae*, you can still describe Ancient Rome and Ancient Greece as having different monetary systems.

Comment: @IMSoP I think the point is there's no indication that The Shire even had their own minted coins. They could very well have just used coins from around Middle Earth by their weight in metal. E.g., until the 13th century England only minted pennies and used Arabic or Byzantine gold coins for larger denominations.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard That's not what the answer says at all, it says that *nowhere in Europe* had a monetary system. I would say that "locally minted pennies with Arabic or Byzantine gold coins for larger denominations" is still a monetary system - I doubt anybody wrote up prices in ounces of copper, they had a set of recognised coins they could refer to, even if they're not all produced locally, and don't form a neat set of multiples.

Comment: @IMSoP Price was in local coins as a local quantum of value, sure. But coins from anywhere else were equally acceptable, at a value which only depended on the weight of the coins (or fractions of coins, as with "pieces of eight" which were one coin cut into fragments to pay for smaller values more conveniently). Foreign coins appeared all over the place, and were used together with local coins with no question about their value. And smaller principalities simply didn't bother minting their own coins as a result. Coinage was a monarch's vanity project, nothing more.

Comment: "There was no need for exchange rates, because you just weighed the coins and that was what they were worth" Technically, there was, because of the fact that coins may not have been made from pure gold/silver/copper. If your silver coin is only 90% silver by weight, it'd only be worth 90% of its weight.

Comment: @Graham OK, then how about we reword the question as "what did hobbits use as their every-day quantum of value?" The distinction between that and a monetary system feels pedantic to me, and the answer remains "there are mentions of coins, but Tolkien didn't discuss details".